# <position> : Missing ')' in method call. - Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to re-purpose a function I found online to remove special characters from a string so I can utilize it as an alias within exchange, but I'm getting the above error.

I can't seem to find what this error is complaining about. Here is the function:

```
Function Convert-ToFriendlyName{
param ($Text)
# Unwanted characters (includes spaces and '-') converted to a regex:
$SpecChars = '!', '"', '£', '$', '%', '&', '^', '*', '(', ')', '@', '=', '+', '¬', '`', '\', '<', '>', '.', '?',     '/', ':', ';', '#', '~', "'", '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '-', ' '
$remspecchars = [string]::join('|', ($SpecChars | % {[regex]::escape($_)}))
# Convert the text given to correct naming format (Uppercase)
$name = (Get-Culture).textinfo.totitlecase(“$Text”.tolower())
# Remove unwanted characters
$name = $name -replace $remspecchars, ""
$name
}
```

Thoughts? Any insight would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: Works for me. What are you feeding it?

Comment: That's odd. When I comment it out, the script runs fine... I'm not feeding it anything yet, just adding the function to the script for now.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the issue is in this line: $name = (Get-Culture).textinfo.totitlecase(“$Text”.tolower()) - Yet when I run that manually, it's fine??

Comment: Sounds like the problem is not with the function itself, but with the insertion into the script.  If you're inserting it at the top of the script, are you sure you didn't get it into the tail end of the param block (before that last closing paren)?

Comment: Yes, in fact I just created a whole new ps1 file with JUST this function and I'm still getting the same error...

Comment: I cannot reproduce that result.

Comment: Tried the same, I'm pretty sure whatever parameter you're supplying this script is causing the error. Can you provide a sample parameter you've used that causing the script to fail?

Comment: Check your file encoding. The characters £, ¬, “, and ” may be causing the problem. Try saving the file using UTF-8. Or refactor $SpecChars:

[char[]]$SpecChars = (0x20..0x2b)+(0x2d..0x40)+0x5c,0x5e,0x60,0x7e,0xa3,0xac

Comment: Thanks all for the input. The issue turned out to be pretty basic, once I removed the double quotes around $Text and replaced with single quotes all was well! DOH!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks all for the input. The issue turned out to be pretty basic, once I removed the double quotes around $Text and replaced with single quotes all was well! DOH! –  user2735454 just now   edit